# ArcObjects .NET 9.3 upgrade to 10 breaks IRasterDataset.Copy(...) code

Tags: arcobjects, raster, enterprise-geodatabase

I have to upgrade an application from ArcObjects 9.3 (C# .NET) to 10. Unfortunately, there seems to be some incompatibility regarding the IRasterDataset.Copy method. The following code worked fine in 9.3:

```
my_raster_dataset.Copy("my_copied_raster", my_sde_workspace);
```

`my_raster_dataset` is a raster dataset called "INPUT_RASTER" loaded from a file geodatabase. `my_sde_workspace` is an ArcSDE 9.3 geodatabase running on SQL Server 2005.

Using ArcObjects 10, I get the following error message:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The table was not found. [VAT_INPUT_RASTER]
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRasterDataset.Copy(String copyName, IWorkspace copyWorkspace)

Any ideas or suggestions? Do I have to upgrade ArcSDE to 10 to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT - Found the answer**

Found the problem. I was checking out `esriLicenseProductCodeEngine` instead of `esriLicenseProductCodeEngineGeoDB`. Strange, that the code worked with ArcObjects 9.3 since 2010 and suddenly stopped working with ArcObjects 10.